# Biblatex - add given name initial and year to style authortitle in footcite

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to add two things in the footcite.

1. Initials of the author
2. The publish year

The footcite should be:

> 1 Vgl. Gastineau, G., The Exchange-Traded Funds Manual, 2010, S. 78.

The reference page should is fine already with

> Gastineau, Gary L. The Exchange-Traded Funds Manual. New York: John Wiley
> & Sons, 2010. isbn: 978-0-470-63734-0.

MWE:

```
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid, sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

@Book{Gastineau2010,
  author    = {Gastineau, Gary L.},
  title     = {The Exchange-Traded Funds Manual},
  isbn      = {978-0-470-63734-0},
  publisher = {John Wiley & Sons},
  address   = {New York},
  year      = {2010},
}

\begin{document}

Text \footcite[~Vgl.][S. 78]{Gastineau2010}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily get "Gastineau, G.", so I hope you are OK with "Gastineau, G. L.".

For the name format in the citation, you need to modify the `labelname` format. In order to also print the date in the citation we add `\printdate` to the `cite` macro ([ll. 10-15 in `authoryear.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authortitle.cbx#L10))

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-ibid]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifnumless{\value{uniquename}}{2}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiveni}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{titleyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}%
     \printdate}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Gastineau2010,
  author    = {Gastineau, Gary L.},
  title     = {The Exchange-Traded Funds Manual},
  isbn      = {978-0-470-63734-0},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons},
  address   = {New York},
  year      = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Text\footcite[Vgl.][78]{Gastineau2010}
\end{document}
```

[image: Vgl. Gastineau, G. L., The Exchange-Traded Funds Manual, 2010, S. 78.]

Note that the ampersand & needs to be escaped to `\&` in the `.bib` file.

There is no need for the "S." in the postnote argument for the page number. `biblatex` can automatically add the required "S." page prefix if you load `babel` or `polyglossia` with the German language module.

I don't think it is good style to include a space at the beginning of the prenote argument (as in `[~Vgl.]`) if you want more space between the footnote number and the text, you should define that globally (how you'd do that may depend on your document class, which isn't shown in the question, so I won't address that here).